# OCaml optimization of List.length for list literals?

Tags: ocaml, compiler-optimization

Does the OCaml compiler at any point make any effort to optimize calls to `List.length` for list literals (or other lists for that matter)?

I have written a trivial program (shown below) and compiled with ocamlopt with varying levels of optimization. Reviewing the generated assembly suggests that each time `List.length` is called, it's an O(n) operation. One would think, given that lists are immutable, the compiler could readily determine the length of a list literal as that is known at compile time, and store that such that `List.length` becomes O(1).

```
let a = [1; 2; 3; 4]

let () = 
  let p i = Printf.printf "%d\n" i in
  p (List.length a);
  p (List.length a)
```

A) Am I really bad at picking apart assembly or specifying optimization levels and this  *is* available?

B) If it's not an optimization the compiler does, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the compiler is not doing any special effort to optimize `List.length`.

There is simply no reason to do so: list literals are a syntactic sugar that only exists in the parser, they are immediately desugared into the constructor form

```
let l = (::)(1, (::)(2,(::)(3,(::)(4,[]))))
```

Moreover, constant propagation and inlining are enough to optimize the call to `List.length a` to the constant 4 as you can see this with

```ml
(* test.ml *)
let test =
  let a = [1;2;3;4] in
  List.length a
```

```bash
ocamlopt -O3 test.ml -dflambda -inline-max-unroll 2
```

> End of middle end:
> let_symbol (camlR (Block (tag 0,  4)))
> End camlR